# Average time to win "Catch (Chase) the Ace!"

Tags: r, probability, simulation

Catch (Chase) the Ace! is a popular lottery card game that is often played to win large sums of money and to donate funds to worthy charities. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chase_the_Ace_(lottery)

Gameplay involves a standard 52-card deck. The objective is to select the Ace of Spades.

According to the Wikipedia Article:

The jackpot accumulates from week-to-week until it is won, and the game is then     over. Each week participants buy lottery tickets. The funds from ticket sales are     divided into three parts. Typically the organizers keep 50% (donated to charity), the winner of the weekly lottery takes 20%, and the remaining 30% goes into the jackpot. The lottery winner also then draws a card from a deck of playing cards and wins the accumulated jackpot if the ace of spades is drawn. If not, the reduced deck is kept for the following week's game, and the jackpot rolls over to the next week.

I'm interested in the mathematical/probabilistic aspects of the game and so wrote a quick R simulation.

```
# Playing Card Alphabet
```

```r
    cards <- c("Ace of Clubs",
           "Ace of Diamonds",
           "Ace of Hearts",
           "Ace of Spades",
           "2 of Clubs",
           "2 of Diamonds",
           "2 of Hearts",
           "2 of Spades",
           "3 of Clubs",
           "3 of Diamonds",
           "3 of Hearts",
           "3 of Spades",
           "4 of Clubs",
           "4 of Diamonds",
           "4 of Hearts",
           "4 of Spades",
           "5 of Clubs",
           "5 of Diamonds",
           "5 of Hearts",
           "5 of Spades",
           "6 of Clubs",
           "6 of Diamonds",
           "6 of Hearts",
           "6 of Spades",
           "7 of Clubs",
           "7 of Diamonds",
           "7 of Hearts",
           "7 of Spades",
           "8 of Clubs",
           "8 of Diamonds",
           "8 of Hearts",
           "8 of Spades",
           "9 of Clubs",
           "9 of Diamonds",
           "9 of Hearts",
           "9 of Spades",
           "10 of Clubs",
           "10 of Diamonds",
           "10 of Hearts",
           "10 of Spades",
           "Jack of Clubs",
           "Jack of Diamonds",
           "Jack of Hearts",
           "Jack of Spades",
           "King of Clubs",
           "King of Diamonds",
           "King of Hearts",
           "King of Spades",
           "Queen of Clubs",
           "Queen of Diamonds",
           "Queen of Hearts",
           "Queen of Spades")


    ## Simulation

    catch.ace <- function(ticket.price = ticket.price, 
      max.num.tickets = max.num.tickets) {
    week <- 0 # initialize counter
    payoff <- 0 # initialize weekly winnings
    jackpot <- 0 # initialize progressive jackpot
  
    while(week < 52) {
      max.num.tickets <- ceiling(runif(1, 1, 75000)) 
                    # maximum number of tickets sold
      week <- week + 1 # increment counter
      tickets <- sample(max.num.tickets, size = 1) 
                         # random number of tickets sold
      fill.envelopes <- sample(cards, size = length(cards), 
                replace = FALSE) # assign cards to envelopes
      pick.ticket <- sample(tickets, size = 1) # select random ticket
      pick.envelope <- sample(fill.envelopes, size = 1) 
                                # choose random envelope
      cards <- cards[!(cards == pick.envelope)] 
                                # remove selected card
      payoff <- tickets * ticket.price # ticket sales
      jackpot <- jackpot + (0.30 * payoff) 
          # update weekly winnings; 30% of ticket sales 
          # goes into jackpot
    
    cat("\n Week: ", week,
        "\n Ticket number: ", pick.ticket,
        "\n Card selected: ", pick.envelope)
    
    if ("Ace of Spades" %in% pick.envelope) {
      cat("\n Outcome: Congratulations, you've selected the Ace of 
       Spades! You've won the progressive jackpot! \n Jackpot: 
         $",jackpot, "\n \n") 
  break
  } else {
    cat("\n Outcome: Sorry, you didn't select the Ace of Spades! 
     Better luck next time! \n Payoff: $",(0.20 * payoff)) 
       # 20% of ticket sales goes to winning ticket holder each week  
      }
    
    cat("\n Proceeds donated to charity: $",(0.50 * payoff), "\n \n") 
       # 50% of all ticket sales goes to charity
    
    }
    cards <- cards # reset deck
    return(list("week" = week,
                "payoff" = payoff,
                "jackpot" = jackpot,
                "tickets" = tickets,
                "fill.envelopes" = fill.envelopes,
                "pick.ticket" = pick.ticket,
                "pick.envelope" = pick.envelope))
    }

## Let's play!

    ticket.price <- 5 # price per ticket
    max.num.tickets <- ceiling(runif(1, 1, 75000)) 
         # maximum number of tickets sold

    catch.ace(ticket.price = ticket.price, 
               max.num.tickets =  max.num.tickets)
```

I wondered about the mean time to winning. So I tried it out, simulating 10000 runs.

### Mean number of weeks to win (similarly, cards to draw)

```r
    mean(replicate(10000, catch.ace(ticket.price = ticket.price, 
      max.num.tickets =  max.num.tickets)$week))
```

The answer is around 26 (52/2) weeks (similarly, 26 cards to draw), which is about 6 months.

### **My question**:

Is there an easy way to arrive at a closed form expression for the expectation and other quantities (such as the variance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine we number the positions in the originally shuffled deck 1 to 52. Assume that the deck is well-shuffled (well enough that we may treat all possible orders of the cards as equally, likely, say).

We're interested in the position of a specific card, which should be uniformly distributed over those positions. That is, the position of the card in the deck after the initial shuffle has a discrete uniform distribution on the values $\{1, 2, 3,..., 52\}$. If the card it's in position $i$, it is drawn in week $i$.

Consequently, for the specific quantities mentioned, your question is simply, what's the mean and variance of a discrete uniform on $\{1, 2, 3,..., 52\}$?

That's a simple matter of calculation from the definitions, we get a mean[1] of $\mu=(1+52)/2 = 26.5$ and variance[2] of $\sigma^2=51\times 53/12=225.25$, or a standard deviation of just over $15$.

However, "other quantities" is too open-ended to say whether it's easily represented in closed form. Many things are easily computed for the [discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) (many things you might care about are in the sidebar there), but it's a bit hard to guess at your ingenuity in coming up with some particularly tricky "other".

However, simulation is a useful strategy in any case, and will yield answers even when there isn't some neat expression. I'd just advise using considerably larger sample sizes -- in R (which is not the fastest way to simulate this, but will do fine), $10^{7}$ simulations of the position takes somewhere between 1 and 2 seconds on my laptop, which is not long to wait.

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case

[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable

Comment: Yes, while an unspecified "other" is a bit nebulous, it is worth noting that all moments of closed form functions of the random variable have a closed form (finite sum) representation.

Comment: Could you explain how the stated prizes might correspond to a "discrete uniform" and exactly what property of the game the mean of this uniform distribution represents?  Although it is evident that $26.5$ represents the expected number of plays needed to win, it doesn't directly reflect the accumulated jackpot (whose increments apparently are considered independent random variables themselves).

Comment: My answer relates to the title "average time to win" and the heading in the body text "mean number of weeks to win". As I read it, that's the aspect that the OP is asking for the mean and variance of.

Comment: @whuber raises an interesting point here regarding the cumulative jackpot. While my title gets at one thing, I also state within the post my general interest in the statistical properties of such a game. This aspect might pique viewer interest. Should I ask a separate question in this respect?

Comment: Given that glen_b has already supplied a nice answer to the first part of the question, creating a separate thread for the second part would be the best approach.

Comment: I don't see it as answering "the first part of the question"; it's answering the actual question that was asked. OP simulates the number of weeks and requests a closed form expression for the mean and variance. No other quantity is requested. This also matches the title; the whole is consistently only actually asking for what was provided. Other aspects of the situation are briefly described but no direct questions are asked about them that I can see. I agree that a second thread would be the best approach, but not because I have left part of this question unanswered ...

Comment: ... The OP does say they have an interest "in other aspects of the game" but does NOT ask for any specific thing in relation to them. That could refer to all manner of possible things, none of which are actually asked for here.